# how do I call a google web app script from another script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm developing an application that uses both a google form and an additional google script web app.When the the form is submitted, a script is triggered. I want that script to call another web app consequently so I can do some GUI operations. Or maybe it might even be possible to run an HTML ui service from the script attached to the form? Is that possible or do I need to call a second web app script?
If you can please give me a brief conceptual implementation of such a thing, or just direct me to the right documentation, it would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I'm not sure what you want when you say

> I want that script to call another web app consequently so I can do some GUI operations.

A Google Apps Script cannot fire an event triggered by a form submittal which launches a browser window or other host for any UI. An already running script or an open Script container (Sheets, Docs or Sites, say) can show UI panels or you can access GA scripts from a web app - both of these could show whatever the last submitted form was.

Or are you asking if the form submitter can be forwarded to a UI post-form submittal? You may send a url to follow-up Ui by email.

---

If you simple want one script to call another as per the question heading you have two options.

- **Attach the second script a a Library and call a function directly.** [[Docs]](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries)

  There are a couple of things to look out for in terms of various shared/non-shared resources. You can find more about that [`here`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries?hl=en#scoping).
- **Publish your second script as a webapp.** [[Docs]](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps)

  You can then call the second script using [`UrlFetchApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/external_apis) either just to initiate a function, or to return content as you need, effectively your own web facing API.

  NB. Your security and access settings will need to suit the functions you are calling.

Comment: Thank you very much. I still can't seem to understand how and where to render the HTML I get form the UtlFetchApp...If I understood you correctly, I call the URL of my web app using the FetchApp and I get in return the output of its doGet(). Where can I make that accessible for the user? The web app is a plain html form, how do I make it available for the user to fill?

Comment: That's what I said wasn't clear in your question. Short answer is that you can't. Second part of answer was answering the question title, in that it IS possible to call another script after form submittal, but I think it isn't possible for it to display UI, just process the form. You could generate a unique url based on the form answer and send that to the respondent.

Comment: So redirecting to a file upload gui created with the UIservice is impossible...Perhaps first letting the user choose a file, then passing the file ID to the form triggered script in some way. after I send the user to fill the form, I can continue processing the file according to the info i got from his form. That's a possibility, isn't it? If it is, how can I make sure the form response will be connected to the right file ID? Can I create a cookie from the script? Or maybe change an input in the form to have the ID as a value? Thanks again :-)

Comment: There are so many what…ifs? involved here. Will one user only use the form once, how are users directed to the form in the first place? Stack Overflow is not the place for conversations. Ask me the question at the GAS Google+ community and we can pick it up there as its not really a code problem. https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/102471985047225101769

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is get rid of the Google Form and create your own form by publishing a web app with the HTML Service. Then you can do what ever you want after the user finishes the form.